# Limit of char count in WP custom fields

Tags: custom-field, database

does anyone of you know what is the limit of chars count which can be stored in to database via WP custom fields? Let's say that I would want to add to custom field 20 000 chars. Would it be problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That field is [`longtext`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table%3a_wp_postmeta) so it should be more than you could ever use-- about [4GB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html)

Comment: Waut thx man, that made my day :)